# How select an item from drop-down of com-box with Enter Key in Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder4.5, flashbuilder4

I want to select item from a combo-box with enter key, is that any built in combo-box event not key-down event.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There are various events you can use to catch this.

For instance all Spark Lists (that includes DropDownList and ComboBox) dispatch an [IndexChangeEvent.CHANGE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/events/IndexChangeEvent.html#CHANGE) whenever, well, the selected index changes. This event carries information on the selected index (`newIndex`) and the one that was just deselected (`oldIndex`).

A more generic event is also dispatched, one that all "input" components dispatch when their value changes: [FlexEvent.VALUE_COMMIT](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/FlexEvent.html#VALUE_COMMIT). This doesn't carry any other information.

Both these events are dispatched regardless of whether an item was selected through mouse click or through keyboard selection.

Perhaps you want to catch just the event that an item was selected through the keyboard. In this case you can listen for either [FlexEvent.ENTER](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/events/FlexEvent.html#ENTER), which is only dispatched when the Enter button is pressed; or for the more generic [KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/KeyboardEvent.html#KEY_UP), in which case you'll have to manually find out whether the pressed key is an enter key or not.